# Initializing disposable resources outside or inside try/finally

Tags: c#, java, coding-style, resources

I have seen two ways of acquiring and disposing resources. Either:

```
Resource resource = getResource();
try { /* do something with resource */ }
finally { resource.close(); }
```

or:

```
Resource resource = null;
try { resource = getResource(); /* do something with resource */ }
finally { if (resource != null) resource.close(); }
```

I was wondering which style is preferable. The first one avoids the `if` condition, while the second one (I presume) handles the case of thread abort right after the assignment but before entering the `try` block. What other pros and cons do these styles have over each other? Which one should I preferably use?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In C#, just use the using statement:

```
using (Resource resource = GetResource())
{
    /* Do something */
}
```

This is the idiomatic way of cleaning up resources, and relies on the resource in question implementing the `IDisposable` interface. (Java now has a similar try-with-resources statement, for resources implementing `AutoCloseable`.)

There's no risk of a thread abort in Java happening between the assignment and entering the try block - aborts only occur during sleeps and waits. EDIT: I can't actually find this in the spec, which is somewhat worrying. Hmm.

Comment: Thank you. C#'s using keyword is great, but sometimes it cannot be used (e.g. with a type that does not implement IDisposable, or when Dispose() should be called conditionally). As for Java, I have no experience actually with such issues, but can't a thread be interrupted?

Comment: they can be interrupted (safely) if you write code to allow it, what really happens is that threads can get signaled that they need to interrupt, and on the thread code you decide how you stop the current work being performed

Comment: Yes - but at least they won't get interrupted post-assignment, pre-entering-try-block. That's the important bit :)

Comment: May I ask how do you know they will not be interrupted between the assignment and the try?

Comment: @Hosam: As I said, I haven't managed to find it in the spec yet, but note that InterruptedException is a *checked* exception, so it can't just be thrown anywhere. I believe that *somewhere* it's documented to only be thrown during blocking operations (wait/sleep/IO etc).

Comment: Thanks Jon. You're helpful as always.

Comment: @Alex: I don't think that's necessary, to be honest. I see no sign of anyone being confused, in the more-than-10-years since this answer have been posted. The OP understood it already (as per the first comment).

Comment: @Alex: I'll edit it in - but you may well find there are a lot of answers to C# tag questions that assume more than a couple of days experience of C#. (Lots will talk about lambda expressions without defining what that means, as an example.) I think it's reasonable that readers look up any terms they're not familiar with - in this case, "using statement" - unless defining the term is the purpose of the question.

Answer (score 4):

first one is preferable

Answer (score -1):

If *getResource()* throws an exception then *resource* will be null, *getResource()* does not return anything in the case of an exception. So, as long as *getResource()* can throw an exception, always check for null before calling *resource.close()*. I feel the best way to organize this code is to put everything inside the try block; make it clear clear that *getResource()* throws exceptions.

Comment: There's no need to do this with the first version though - if the exception is thrown, you won't reach the finally block.

Comment: In similar code where, say, a lock is being acquired and released, a failure in acquisition would result in an unmatched release.